# Can we use Mapstaction API with Google Map API v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, mapstraction

The [demo](http://mapstraction.appspot.com/#google) on their site is based on Google Map API version 2. So, is Google Map API version 3 also supported. How can I use that to switch from version 2 to version 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps v3 API is supported by Mapstraction v2 - you use the "googlev3" provider ID.

https://github.com/mapstraction/mxn/wiki